# PHP - Passing pdo connection query via php function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So i'm trying to pass PDO Query by using php, like this(index.php):

```
include("dbconn.php");
mysqlConnect("'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name =' . $conn->quote($name))", "jeff");
```

while my dbconn file that  contains the function is(dbconn.php):

```
function mysqlConnect($queryString, $name) {

    // DB Credentials
    $dbName = 'db';
    $dbUser = 'root';
    $dbPass = '';
    $dbHost = 'localhost';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Here goes the first parameter, then it uses the second parameter as a variable
    $data = $conn->query($queryString);
    // So the output should be this:
    // $data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = ' . $conn->quote($name));

    foreach($data as $row) {
        print_r($row); 
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

So in my function call the php actually executes the `$conn->quote($name))` code, making my application not work.

How should i do this? is this allowed in php?

**Edit:**

or in other words: i call a function and give it 2 parameters, one of the parameters(even tho it's in double quotes) is executed by php which shouldn't happen. How can i fix this

Comment: What you are trying to do??

Comment: **1)** what is `mysqlConnect`? **2)** Where (and what) is `$conn->quote($name)`, and what should it do? **3)** What do you mean by *pass PDO Query by using php, like this while my dbconn file that contains the function*?

Comment: try `'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ='.$conn->quote($name)`... but also, read about SQL injection and avoid passing direct variables to your query string

Comment: Is `mysqlConnect` always only taking one query parameter? Not seeing `$name` usage in your function..

Comment: @AlanMachado mysqlConnect(); is a function i defined in the dbconn file, while $conn->quote($name) is just a PDO equivalent to mysql_real_escape_string also the thing you said didn't help

Comment: @chris85 mysqlConnect takes 2 parameters, i separated them by comma first one is the actual query while the second one is the name query needs to find

Comment: So basically all i'm asking is this: i call a function and give it 2 parameters, one of the parameters(even tho it's in double quotes) is executed by php which shouldn't happen. How can i fix this

Comment: So, you did `mysqlConnect('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ='.$conn->quote($name), 'jeff');` and it still doesn't work? What error output you are receiving?

Comment: @AlanMachado  Undefined variable: name would be the error that i got

Comment: oh and this one after i done what you said: Fatal error: Call to a member function quote() on a non-object

Comment: Yes. You received that error because `$conn` is not an object that contains the function `quote()`, so you can't call it with `->`. And about the `Undefined variable` notice, where's `$name` ever used inside your `mysqlConnect()` ? I didn't find it.

Comment: `$conn` is a `PDO` class instance, and there is no method called `quote()` inside `PDO` class.

Comment: So the first parameter given in the function call goes to this line: $data = `$conn->query($queryString);`, while the second one is used by the first one, but it only has to be done when the parameters are inserted into place

Comment: The variable `$name` doesn't exists until you called the function. The parameter "jeff" came after its call, meaning nothing was called. The variable **must** be defined before the function calling.

Comment: Like `$name = "jeff"; mysqlConnect('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ='.$conn->quote($name));` (and redefine your function to accept only one parameter)

Comment: @AlanMachado, thanks that works, you can now post it as an answer if you wish (i'll accept it) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote, it will never work. You just have to learn to distinguish a **string literal** from executable code.

Anyways, you don't need such a frankenstein at all. There is already a mechanism to put your variable in the query, called **prepared statements**. You just have to use them.

There are other issues with your code too. I've described them all in the article I wrote recently, [The only proper guide on PDO](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo), I am sure you will find it interesting - all the issues like wrong error handling, utterly wrong way to connect, lack of prepared statements - all described there. Having all of them solved, here goes the proper function you need:

```
function pdo($sql, $data=[]) 
{
    global $pdo; // you can add a call to your favorite IoC here.
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    return $stmt;
}
```

used as

```
include("dbconn.php");
$user = pdo("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?", ["jeff"])->fetch();
var_dump($user);
```

this is how PDO have to be used.

By returning a statement, you'll be able to use all the power of PDO, getting data you need in one line, say a list

```
$news = pdo("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC")->fetchAll();
var_dump($news); // already an array
```

or just a single value

```
$count = pdo("SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE author=?", [$id])->fetchColumn();
var_dump($count); // already a number
```

or simply by iterating results one by one

```
$news = pdo("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC")->fetchAll();
foreach ($news as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

and so on.